# Databricks AutoML - dataset upload

Tags: python, dataset, azure-databricks, automl

Whenever I upload a dataset into Databricks to run an AutoML experiment, Databricks automatically truncates the dataset to 1000 rows. Is there any way that I can, for example, upload a dataset with 9000+ rows into the data section of Databricks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Databricks is sampling dataset to avoid out-of-memory issues.

If you are using Databricks Runtime 9.1 LTS ML or above, AutoML automatically samples your dataset if it is too large to fit into the memory of a single worker node.

**Workaround –**

Try to select Worker type with more memory.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/machine-learning/automl#limitations